# how to filter post by a field in the firestore collection document

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to filter out posts by 'hidingUserId', which is an array of 'userId's in the collection 'reviews'. pls, see the pic. user with the id in the 'hidingUserId' array will not see the post he/she has hidden. Later I query these posts and order them by stars, likes, and/or timestamp.

[image: firestoredata]

In the rules simulator I can play around with set IDs and it works fine. However, when I test the app on the phone, I get following error:

```
[Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(reviews order by -stars, - 
timestamp, -__name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: 
Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient 
permissions., cause=null}
```

Not all posts have 'hidingUserId', as not all posts will be hidden by users. My firestore rules are:

```
  match /reviews/{review}{
 allow read: if request.auth != null && !(request.auth.uid in 
 resource.data.hidingUserId)
 allow delete, update, create: if request.auth != null
 }
```

thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
String myID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    var idofotheruser = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('reviews')
        .where('hidingUserId' arrayContains: myID )
//.get or .snapshot
        .get();
```

Comment: thanks, but i am having trouble with .where() and .orderBy(). i am ordering the posts according to stars, then likes, then timestamp and stars descending. whenever, I have .where() then I get errors requiring .orderBy() to be the same field. it was very confusing.

Comment: you cant have trouble using where and order in that way, share your code... i beleve you are using doc() with where...

Comment: plus, array should not contain the userId, as the user has hidden the post as not to see it, so it should not appear on the users wall/screen..i dont understand this

Comment: apologies! :) user hides the posts, and userId is set in the 'hidingUserId' array. this user then sees only posts that he/she did not hide, in other words 'hidingUserId' array does not contain his/her userId. if we use your suggestion than posts hidden by the user will be visible to the user.

Comment: i am busy nw, i will read and get back to u... please..

Comment: @HaKim how i understand, you dont want user to see the hidden post, that means you create another collect for hidden post with the id of the post, so each time steam fetch the normal post it check the id of the hidden post id and remove i from the post..... hope you understand

Comment: thanks, so u suggest that i cross check the Ids of the post and the hidingUserId then stream the result? so, does this mean I need to create two list variables, cross check them then .orderBy() the results? would this incur additional charges on firestore?

Comment: what i means is that, a create sub collection of the hidden post, after that in the new post when you have fetch it should check the id of the hidden if is part of the id of the post, and is part it should remove it from list

Comment: i am confused, can u pls, show me how to do it? tnx!